# What is the logic in this code?

Tags: c++, logic

I am having a hard time understanding the following code:

```
if ((number % 10)> max) //rem of 10
{
    max = (number % 10);
}
number /= 10;
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Aren't you understanding how `if` works or what the operators do ? Explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: `%` gives remainder, `number /= 10` is same as `number = number/10`

Answer (score 3):

I guess the code you posted is the body of a loop, like this:

```
int max = 0;
while (number != 0) {
    if (number % 10 > max) {
        max = number % 10;
    }
    number /= 10;
}
```

This loop finds the largest decimal digit of number. E.g. if `number==152`, you will get `max==5` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

- `(number % 10)`, gives remainder of `number` on dividing by `10`.
- `(number % 10) > max`, means if the remainer is greater than `max`.

So if the remainder is greater than `max`, them make `max` the remainder as:

```
       max = (number % 10);
```

And `number/=10` is a shorthand of

```
 number = number/10; //same as number /= 10;
```

which divides `number` by 10, and saves the quotient in `number`.

There are other shorthands in C++ as well:

```
 a += x; // a = a + x;
 a -= x; // a = a - x;
 a *= x; // a = a * x;
 a %= x; // a = a % x; //if a and x are integral type, if they're built-in type.
```

If the type of `a` is class, then you can overload all these operators for your class.

Answer (score 1):

If the last digit of `number` is larger than `max`:

```
if ((number % 10)> max)
```

Then `max` equals the last digit

```
max = (number % 10);
```

Remove the last digit

```
number /= 10;
```

When you put this in a loop, it let's you find the largest digit in the `number`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the same job but in a more understandable way. It also runs faster as the number of divisions, which are computationally expensive, is minimized (each `%` in your code implicitly involves a division).

```
// given: a positive integer 'number'
// sought-for: the maximum decimal digit in 'number'
int maxReminder = 0;
while (number != 0) {
    // find the quotient of the division of 'number' by 10
    int divQuotient = number/10;
    // find the reminder of the division above
    int divReminder = number - divQuotient*10;
    if (divReminder > maxReminder) {
        // 'divReminder' is the new maximum reminder
        maxReminder = divReminder;
    }
    // prepare for the next iteration
    number = divQuotient;
}
// 'maxReminder' now holds the sought-for
```